# How to resolve #N/A error with vlookup involving a database query return in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm getting a strange #N/A error excel/vlookup. I have a database connection with sql query returning a lot of rows ~40k. I have a field with two data values separated with a comma. I am breaking these up with a right(cell, 9) to obtain the lookup value.

Then, am crafting the vlookup formula to lookup that value on a worksheet with that value and another cooresponding value. However, this results in an #N/A error. The cells where I am putting the formula is part of the sql result return and this forces the formula to be pushed onto every row in the table. In otherwords, `=vlookup([@[I/E FINAL]],worksheetrangeA:C,3,false)/`

I know if I hard code the lookup value into the vlookup it does return a legit result. Unsure how to work around this.

Comment: Make sure there are no extra spaces on front or end of the value in the table.

Comment: believe i fixed by forcibly re-formatting the lookup value by doing text-to-column import ontop of itself. the column was formatted as general, but after text-to-column with format of general....vlookup suddenly working.